# Using integer ids with CQRS Pattern

Tags: cqrs

I've been asked to apply the CQRS pattern to an existing project. If at all possible this should not make for any schema changes to the database, which uses integer ids.

However, every example of CQRS I've seen uses Guids, my question is is this an inherent requirement of using CQRS or is there a way I can adapt it.

(We're doing this as an exercise, so the usefulness / practicality of doing such a thing isn't in question).

Comment: How can you don't make any changes to the schema as CQRS splits the model into two: write and read?

Comment: I don't see why that means the database schema has to change? As it is the code uses the repository pattern and every function is either writing or reading.

Comment: You are talking about CQS, not CQRS. In CQRS you have two "repositories", two database tables or even two databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why CQRS should require GUIDS. If you want multiple write services you typically need GUIDS, but CQRS is just about separating the read and write services (and the models used by the two).

Answer (score 2):

Since one aspect of using CQRS is that you can use it to create a (large) distributed application, not having a UUID, but an integer ID may hurt the system's ability to work in a distributed fashion.

The problem here is that you rely on a central counter that needs locking, transactions, and all these kinds of things you do not want to have in a distributed system.

So, yes, of course you *can* use an integer ID, but in terms of scalability it's a bad idea. If this isn't important for you, it will (probably) work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

CQRS requires guids as the source of a command has to be independent of any central dispatch of IDs. They are easy to generate. Where a standard library doesn't provide you with a guid, crypto libraries are actually better. Here's what I use for Go:

```
func pseudo_uuid() (uuid string) {

    b := make([]byte, 16)
    _, err := rand.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
        return
    }

    uuid = fmt.Sprintf("%X-%X-%X-%X-%X", b[0:4], b[4:6], b[6:8], b[8:10], b[10:])

    return
}
```

While looking at CQRS as just a way to separate a system into 2 systems - one that takes care of state transitions and one for everything else - it is important to observe that the motivation for CQRS is scalability and the the abstractions you build by relying on a central dispatch of IDs will cost you a refactoring effort as you scale up.